# Apache Velocity 2.0 - log binding issue?

Tags: java, logging, velocity

I'm using Apache Velocity 2.0. I'm trying to set slf4j binding. As described within Apache Velocity documents I've set required dependencies.
Such done & said I'm expecting now to use NOPLogger as don't have any log usage. My code is following:

```
// Get template engine
VelocityEngine templateEngine = new VelocityEngine();

// Init template engine
templateEngine.addProperty(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_INSTANCE, new NOPLoggerFactory().getLogger(""));
templateEngine.init();
```

My issue is executing "new VelocityEngine();" I'm getting following trace within my debugger console :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://23.fwk288994035:3/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://23.fwk288994035:8/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
```

???

I've got so a look to Apache source code:

```
public class VelocityEngine implements RuntimeConstants
{
    private RuntimeInstance ri = new RuntimeInstance();
....
}

public class RuntimeInstance implements RuntimeConstants, RuntimeServices
{
/**
* The Runtime logger.  The default instance is the "org.apache.velocity" logger.
*/
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DEFAULT_RUNTIME_LOG_NAME);
....
}
```

Sounds to me so logger is get prior integrator get capability to specify it ...
Within my environment. I may already have some other logger running (third party contributions I'm relying on) and so I'm getting such boring trace.

Is my analysis ok? Any trick to share about to get rid about issue?

Comment: What are your slf4j jars?

Comment: I've added sl4j-api plus sl4j-simple jars as addon to Apache's velocity ones. As expecting to set NOPLogger by then end I've got a try to remove sl4j-simple one but velocity is failing at that time ....  Thinking issue is always same velocity is requiring a logger prior providing capability to define it ... so logger finder is running ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning about duplicate slf4j jars,see [explanation](https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html):

> When multiple bindings are available on the class path, select one and only one binding you wish to use, and remove the other bindings. For example, if you have both slf4j-simple-1.8.0-alpha2.jar and slf4j-nop-1.8.0-alpha2.jar on the class path and you wish to use the nop (no-operation) binding, then remove slf4j-simple-1.8.0-alpha2.jar from the class path.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Unfortunately I've read already such. Issue is I'm not fully managing class path. Third party contribution are contributing to it implicitly ... I'm working on an Eclipse RCP application. Third party plugins I'm requiring may already have for sure their own logging concerns. I cannot break them ... My expectation is to act on what I can. I'm managing Velocity engine instantiation so my whish is to fully control it being able to apply logger I want to it for example ...

Answer (score 0):

<del>If you need to keep slf4j-simple in the classpath, you simply *cannot* also add the slf4j-nop jar.</del>

There simply *cannot* be two slf4j binding jars in the classpath.

What you need to do is turn off Velocity logs, by means of [configuring the SimpleLogger](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html).

For instance, you can define the following system property:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.velocity = off
```

Comment: org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLogger is provided Thanks sl4j-api.jar no need for extra sl4j-nop.jar. sl4j-api.jar is mandatory requirement for velocity.

I've got a try to set system property in sync. with your advice but result is same ... still getting bindings warnings. I've looked for other existing bindings within my third party plugins for sure log4j is present.

Comment: The warning states that there are two slf4j implementations, so there must be one somewhere hidden in your classpath...

Comment: For sure there's some. Some third party plugins are relying on to bind to log4j. Unfortunately I've no control on such plugin contribution to classpath. I may be ok such it's a pity such plugin is not allowing control on logger but back to velocity sounds to me proper material is available to integrator to setup logger except logger is used prior taking such setup into account ...

Comment: Just as a try I've got Apache velocity sources. I've hacked RuntimeInstance.class having logger usage only post initializeLog() call. I've build back a velocity.jar from such. Relying on such hack, keeping my original code setting RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_INSTANCE property prior init() is providing me expected result ... Still thinking some issue within current velocity code in sync. with my first guess analysis or definitively something I'm missing. If so please advice !

Comment: slf4j is supposed to do a *static* initialization, which means that your original problem is still here: you've got two slf4j bindings in your classpath. Your hack probably only postpones the loading of the slf4j classes. It just means that there is no use of slf4j before Velocity is loaded - Velocity's use of slf4j is nothing but totally standard.

Comment: Definitively I'm not a sl4j / logging expert.Let's just share my integrator high level point of view. Building my application I'm collecting many jars, plugin etc. from third parties. Each may have a logging service need. My guess is some of such contributors are using logging service without relying on sl4j. For example I may have one using directly log4j ... so adding such to classpath. On my side I'm using then velocity ... as a binding is already defined within classpath means I've no choice about : I've to inherit from third party choice ???? even if I'm expecting to get no logger usage ?

Comment: My guess is my hack is preventing some slf4j classes usage. Logger is defined up front so no need to resolve it. As far as my defined logger is implementing expected interface stuff is running.

Comment: The slf4j logic is that packages should **never** provide an slf4j binding, but let the user choose the one he wants. So you could dig into your packages to find where does the binding come from to avoid patching Velocity.

Comment: I fully agree your point about binding free implementation. Logger abstraction usage is to me good (best) practice but not mandatory one. Back if I've to rely on a plugin using a logger without abstraction I'm stucked ... 
I'm convinced velocity is implemeting nicely slf4j. My point about velocity is I'm able to see almost everything ready to support if required, integrator provided explicit logger ... what's solving some integration issues ...

Comment: Nevertheless  still I'm a bit disturb by early logger usage within Runtime class initialization steps prior  initializeLog() call what's bottleneck to me.